# why is input type = number value is empty when i trigger function

Tags: javascript, html

When I type a number it give me e.code of first number that I put and input value empty if i type another number it's give's me e.code of the number but its value is first number value

```
   var input = document.getElementById('w-input');
        var kg = document.getElementById('kg');

        input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.code === 'Numpad1'|| e.code==='Numpad2'|| e.code==='Numpad3' || 
               e.code==='Numpad4'|| e.code==='Numpad5'|| e.code==='Numpad6'||
               e.code==='Numpad7'|| e.code==='Numpad8'|| e.code==='Numpad9'||  
               e.code==='Numpad0') {
                   console.log(e.code);
                   lbsToKg();
             }
   });

   function lbsToKg() {
    console.log(input.value);
    kg.innerHTML = input.value * 0.45359237;

   }
```

It should get the input value and multiply it with the number but its not multiplying  it gives 1-9 number 0 means the value is empty . If i type 12 it gives the  0.45359237 as result means it's multiplying it with 1 not 12

Comment: you can use e.which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keypress` is triggered before input change value. Use `keyup` it is triggered after input change value

```js
function print(inp,e) {
    console.log(inp.value);
}
```

```html
<input onkeypress="print(this,event)" placeholder='keypress'>
<input onkeyup="print(this,event)" placeholder='keyup'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Kamil's answered the question about why the value wasn't correct, but you can also reduce the amount of code you use checking for the pressed key which you might find useful.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('w-input');
var kg = document.getElementById('kg');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  // grab the code and the value from the event
  const { code, target: { value } } = e;

  // if the code is "Numpad" followed by a number call the function
  // with the value
  if (/Numpad[0-9]/.test(code)) lbsToKg(value);
});

function lbsToKg(value) {
  kg.innerHTML = value * 0.45359237;
}
```

**Documentation**

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- RegExp [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)